# Removing Time Stamp from Dates in a CSV File

Tags: excel, csv

I have several CSV file that total up to 100000 rows and that I plan on importing into a MySQL database and I need to remove the Time from the date and add the comma after the number. I only need the comma there long enough to switch the row to short date prior to importing it to MySQL

Currently the data is formatted like you see below.

```
Sep  1 2007 12:00AM
Sep  6 2007  2:29PM
Sep  6 2007  4:55PM
Sep 10 2007 10:59AM
Sep 10 2007  4:23PM
Sep 11 2007 11:47AM
Sep 11 2007  4:39PM
```

Can anyone recommend a quick and painless way to do this in excel?

Comment: I can't exactly say, (I don't know if these are in the same cell or not) but TRIM(), LEFT(), MID(), RIGHT(), and maybe even DATE() should work well. Make a formula that works for the first ten cells or so, then apply it on down!

Comment: If the data isn't a string, but date serial, then `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))` will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably around about way of doing it but I solved this by `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(A2,11))," ",", ",2)` this convert it to the following format which will convert into the short date format.

```
Sep 6, 2007
Sep 6, 2007
Sep 10, 2007
Sep 10, 2007
Sep 11, 2007
Sep 11, 2007
Sep 13, 2007
Sep 17, 2007
Sep 17, 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its all text based and also assuming that the first 11 characters are the date fields (3 for month, 2 for day, 4 for year and 2 spaces), `=LEFT(A1, 11)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would dump it in Excel, use text to columns to split it out to 2 columns (fixed width), delete the new second column then save back out to CSV, it would litteraly take longer to open the file than it would to perform the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just import all of the data then delete the column after import.
Range("C:C").ClearContents

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the column list you want to split by delimiter, and click Data > Text to Columns. 
In your case the delimiter looks like it's a space.
This should write the MM DD YYYY into 3 different columns for each.

You can then use the CONCATENATE function to put them back together, but ignoring the column with the date

=CONCATENATE(,"-",,"-",)